# associative array with web form

Tags: php

good day all ,, I am new learner and trying to make an associative array for jobs which user inputs the id, title and description but it is not correct ,,can u guide me through this ?

I also want to search for jobs by its title or description and return the job id ,

Thanks alot

```
<html>
<body>
This form is for storing array of jobs with ID and description for each 
<form method = "post" >
input job iD <input id="jobid"> 
input jobname <input id="jobname"> 
Write a description <input id="jobdesc">  
<input type="submit" value="click to store input" > 
</form>

</body>
</html>

<?php
$jobs_array = array();
$jobs_array[] = array ($_POST['jobid'] ,$_POST['jobname'], $_POST['jobdesc']);
?>
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean - could you expand on what you'd expect to see?

Comment: Theres nothing exactly wrong with your php except that youre creating a crazy multi-dimensional array and you probably dont mean to, most of your problem lies in your form markup

Comment: oh ok ,, what about if i want to add multiple jobs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tweaked your markup a bit to

```
<html>
<body>
    <p>This form is for storing array of jobs with ID and description for each </p>
    <form action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method = "post" >
        <p><label for = "jobid">input job iD</label> <input type = "text" name = "jobid" id="jobid"></p>
        <p><label for = "jobname">input jobname</label><input type = "text" name = "jobname" id="jobname"></p>
        <p><label for = "jobdesc">Write a description</label><input type = "text" name = "jobdesc" id="jobdesc">  
        <input type="submit" value="click to store input" > 
    </form>

</body>
</html>

<?php
    $jobs_array = array ($_POST['jobid'] ,$_POST['jobname'], $_POST['jobdesc']);
?>
```

you can access `jobid` with `$jobs_array[0]` now, and so on.

Comment: thanks for your comment ,, well I think the html part is ok but the php is what is not working ,, right ?
please also advise me the reason u added $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']  ?

Comment: @RawanNj `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` simply echos out the current page to use as the submit page to process the PHP, if you use what i have it should for sure work, just use `echo $jobs_array[0]` etc to get what you need from the array. The html inputs needed the name attribute in orber to be sent correctly

Comment: thanks the $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] is helpful ...
but how can I add multiple jobs ? that's why I thought it should be multidimensional .what do u think ?

Comment: @RawanNj Not exactly sure what you mean by multiple jobs, if you're talking about adding multiple jobs in the one text field. Then you could seperate each job by commas and explode based on the comma, etc

Comment: i mean that this array will save only one job right ? 
when I input a job from the form ,, the array will be filled with this one job .. but then I want to add another job ... the contents of the array will be replaced by the new job 
my question is if I want to add another job into the form after submitting the first one and keeping both in the array ..how can this be implemented ?

Comment: @RawanNj You're correct, the new values will replace the old. One way to get around this would be to store the old data in a MySQL database, that way it is there whenever you need it however long you need it

Comment: I understand ,, but i mean can it be done by arrays only without using sql??

Comment: @RawanNj Sorry for the late reply, the best solution here is to store youre data in a database, every time you resubmit the form the old data will be lost, a possible way to achieve what you are trying would be to submit the form with jquery and store all the data in html5s' `data` attributes.: http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/ then the data wil always be there until the page is refreshed

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to separate the values like

```
$_POST['jobid'] ,$_POST['jobname'], $_POST['jobdesc']
```

and enclose them in an array. Because, they are originally formed that way. When a user submits a post with multiple values, all those values are stored in the super global array `$_POST` so, instead of separating and then, attaching them inside an array, just depend on this one only, because it has all you need inside.

`$all_arrays = $_POST;`

Comment: I mean, the `$_POST` global already contains inside it, all the information you want. later you can even say `$p = $_POST` and echo out `$p['jobname']` or `$p['jobid']` So, no need to insert all arrays inside one big array

Comment: @RawanNj here is a better idea I forgot. Just do `if($_POST): var_dump($_POST); endif;` Now, copy the code and check it out, the `var_dump` function will be help you understand more

Comment: that is really nice I tried it and it prints all the array with its inputs in a neat way :) thanks friend :)

Comment: @RawanNj good. Just make sure not to use `var_dump` in a real code, that is just for testing the values of an array or a variable only. it is only used for debugging.

Comment: One last thing, make sure to 'accept' the answer that helped you, so your question can be marked as 'answered'

Answer (score 0):

An associative array is one where you have a value in an array which can be accessed by a key - that acts as the index.

In your code, as shown below, you are assigning a value to the array without a key thus it isn't associative. Furthermore, you are adding an array to the array making it multidimensional which is inappropriate in this situation.

```
$jobs_array[] = array ($_POST['jobid'] ,$_POST['jobname'], $_POST['jobdesc']);
```

The code should look like this:

```
$jobs_array = array("job_id" => $_POST['jobid'], "job_name" => $_POST['jobname'], "job_description" => $_POST['jobdesc']);
```

Also, the reason why the $_POST variables are not set is because you're using `id` rather than `name`. `id` refers to the stylesheet whereas `name` refers to how the data in the field can be accessed.

For the second part of your question, you need to be using a database to store the jobs, and from there, you can run queries whereby you are able to search through the rows by its id, and return an array of results.

Comment: Thanks alot for the great explanation yes right the two concepts mixed a little now what associative array means is clear thanks @max_ ,,, but can I input multiple jobs in this way ? that was the reason i was trying to make it multinational but not sure how

Comment: for the second part ,, i want to access it by the array it self without connecting to a database ..it can work right ?